# Selecting all check boxes when only clicking one

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

How can I select all the check boxes on single click, while every check box has unique name using JavaScript? Please provide code.

```
 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
 <div class="box-body">
 <form name="permissionfrm" method="post" id="permissionfrm">
 <input type="hidden" name="permission" id="permission" value="assignpermission" />
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Give All Permissions
      </th><td><input type="checkbox" name="addadmin" id="addadmin" value="Check All" onClick="this.value=check(this.form.list)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Add</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a common class. Add the `common class` to all input `checkbox`

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"...
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In jQuery on button click:

```
$('.check').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The good way to use will be assign the class name same to those whom do you want to check after clicking that specific element.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="class_name" >
```

And now `jquery` will do the work for you.
After the click event of the element make the checkbox to checked

```
$(".class_name").click(function(){
    $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Here id `mycheckbox` is the `id's` of all the checkbox to which you want to make checkbox checked.

Hope this helps you!!